# Show and Hide options are captured commonly to single Id in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here when I click the glyphicon it has to display a show hide function for a single column. Where now when I click the glyphicon it shows the function commonly for the first one only.

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7vcqpo0t/2/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12" style="width: 100%" <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Driver</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Cell Phone</th>
        <th>Acct To</th>
        <th>Container#</th>
        <th>Ord Typ</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Sched From</th>
        <th>Sched To</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
      </tr>


      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span></button></td>

        <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
        <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
        <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <form name="form1" method="post" action="DRVAPP100C.PGM">
                  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name="SUBMIT">
        </td>
        &nbsp;
        <input name=SCR type=hidden value="SM">
        <input name=DRVA type=hidden value="/%DRVA%/">
        <input name=DRVC type=hidden value="/%DRVC%/">
        <input name=SMSTXT type=text>
        </form>
        <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name=SMSTXT>
SEND</button>
 -->&nbsp;
        <a href="DRVCNTC.PGM?&account=/%DRVA%/&driver=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Mobile App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=DT&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Show Text</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M1&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Update App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M2&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Thank You</button></a>
        <!--  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"/> -->

        </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span></button></td>

        <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
        <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
        <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <form name="form1" method="post" action="DRVAPP100C.PGM">
                  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name="SUBMIT">
        </td>
        &nbsp;
        <input name=SCR type=hidden value="SM">
        <input name=DRVA type=hidden value="/%DRVA%/">
        <input name=DRVC type=hidden value="/%DRVC%/">
        <input name=SMSTXT type=text>
        </form>
        <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name=SMSTXT>
SEND</button>
 -->&nbsp;
        <a href="DRVCNTC.PGM?&account=/%DRVA%/&driver=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Mobile App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=DT&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Show Text</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M1&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Update App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M2&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Thank You</button></a>
        <!--  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"/> -->

        </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Please do not try to cheat SO by adding a tag to be allowed to post a link to JSFiddle. Instead click the `<>` and post the code HERE!

Comment: Also WHEN you post code that is not dependent on the server, post the RENDERED code. It is now unreadable with all those /%DADRVC%/ /%NMEFRS%/ /%PHNCEL%/ /%DAACCO%/ /%DACNT#%/ /%DAORDT%/ /%DASTRD%/ /%DASTRT%/ /%DASAFR%/ /%DASATO%/ /%DAORDS%/ - please produce a [mcve]

Comment: Also do NOT wrap a button in a link. Instead style the link as a button or have a button with an event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/7vcqpo0t/3/)**.

You've to change the duplicate id's  `demo1` should be `demo2` in the second button since the id should be unique in the same document :

```
<div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo2">
```

Change the `data-target` too :

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12" style="width: 100%" <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Driver</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Cell Phone</th>
        <th>Acct To</th>
        <th>Container#</th>
        <th>Ord Typ</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Sched From</th>
        <th>Sched To</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
      </tr>


      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span></button></td>

        <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
        <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
        <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <form name="form1" method="post" action="DRVAPP100C.PGM">
                  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name="SUBMIT">
        </td>
        &nbsp;
        <input name=SCR type=hidden value="SM">
        <input name=DRVA type=hidden value="/%DRVA%/">
        <input name=DRVC type=hidden value="/%DRVC%/">
        <input name=SMSTXT type=text>
        </form>
        <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name=SMSTXT>
SEND</button>
 -->&nbsp;
        <a href="DRVCNTC.PGM?&account=/%DRVA%/&driver=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Mobile App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=DT&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Show Text</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M1&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Update App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M2&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Thank You</button></a>
        <!--  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"/> -->

        </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span></button></td>

        <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
        <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
        <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo2"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <form name="form1" method="post" action="DRVAPP100C.PGM">
                  <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name="SUBMIT">
        </td>
        &nbsp;
        <input name=SCR type=hidden value="SM">
        <input name=DRVA type=hidden value="/%DRVA%/">
        <input name=DRVC type=hidden value="/%DRVC%/">
        <input name=SMSTXT type=text>
        </form>
        <!-- &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d" name=SMSTXT>
SEND</button>
 -->&nbsp;
        <a href="DRVCNTC.PGM?&account=/%DRVA%/&driver=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Mobile App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=DT&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Show Text</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M1&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Update App</button></a>
        <a href="DRVAPP100C.PGM?scr=M2&DRVA=/%DRVA%/&DRVC=/%DRVC%/">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
 Thank You</button></a>
        <!--  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"/> -->

        </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: thanks @zakaria Acharki for your valuable answer. It's working now. But my concern is what happens when I capture multiple data from database Will it get adapt for all the columns?

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh you can do lots of things in the case of fetching data from the database, like using the id of the columns instead of the number after demo id... or do it with jquery for loop....

Comment: All i want is to generate id dynamically to many columns through database @zakaria Acharki

Comment: Yes you can @Ajay_Venkatesh , you have just to fill the same id in the `id` and the related `data-target` attributes.

Comment: Congratulations, you've earned the **[VoteUp privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)** consider to use it, if any answer from the posted here is what you're looking for Mark it as the **[correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**.